# Add items if equal to (XML feed reading)

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

i am reading an XML feed  and adding results like this:

```
 XElement _xml;
        try
        {
            if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                _xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                Results.Items.Clear();
                foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("runner").Elements("rr_event"))
                {
                    FeedItem _item = new FeedItem();
                    _item.Title = value.Element("title").Value;
                    _item.Description = Regex.Replace(value.Element("description").Value,
                    @"<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty);
                    _item.Sector = value.Element("sector").Value;

   Results.Items.Add(_item);

                }
            }
        }
```

My aim is to only add to Results if the XML tag "Sector" text equals to "A"

Many thanks. Dan

Comment: if(_item.Sector == "A") - if it isn't correspond to the question - rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally agree with vortex, just add `if("A".equals(_item.Sector))`.

```
 XElement _xml;
        try
        {
            if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                _xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                Results.Items.Clear();
                foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("runner").Elements("rr_event"))
                {
                    FeedItem _item = new FeedItem();
                    _item.Title = value.Element("title").Value;
                    _item.Description = Regex.Replace(value.Element("description").Value,
                    @"<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty);
                    _item.Sector = value.Element("sector").Value;

                    if("A".equals(_item.Sector)) Results.Items.Add(_item);
                }
            }
        }
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thanks guys. More simple than I thought! It didnt like the .equals so I replaced it with ==

Comment: Yes, it's not equals but Equals with big E, but in C# == also works for comparing 2 Strings ... It's in Java that you have to use only Equals :)

Comment: Hi, Just one further question to this, how can I do if "A" AND "B" equals the item? Thanks.